# How tax relates with utility function?

Tags: microeconomics, taxation

Suppose there are $n$ agents in an economy and the utility of person $i$ is given by $U_i(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$ where $x_j$ denotes the distance driven by each agent in the economy. One's utility depends on how much others drive due to road congestion and pollution. To contain road congestion, the local government decides to impose a unit-tax on the distance covered by each individual. Unit tax here refers to a tax on each kilometre a person drives.

How does the tax interact with a person's utility? I know that less kilometres will be travelled due to the tax, but I can't say anything beyond that. Is $U_i^{new} = U_i^{old} - tx_i$ a valid way of introducing the tax to the utility function?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you can make up any assumption on utility you want so you could in principle say that: $U_i^{new} = U_i^{old} - tx_i$ however this is very crude way of introducing an effect of taxation.

Here you are basically assuming the tax will not change peoples behavior of how much they are driving. Rather you just assume it affects their welfare and that's it. However, we know that people respond to incentives so it is not good way to model effect of tax this way.

What you should rather do is to explicitly model how distance travelled is affected by tax. Next the utility after tax will be just utility with new distances travelled.

If you want to follow this advice your new utility should look like this:

$$U_i(x_1(t), x_2(t), \cdots, x_n(t))$$

Next add some budget constraint, agents can drive only if they can afford it, so add something like:

$$w_i=(1+t)px_i$$

where $w$ would be person's budget for travel $t$ tax $p$ price of travelling 1 unit of distance by the agent. To make it more interesting you could also add some alternative to travel by car. Maybe agent could take public transport so you would have:

$$U_i(x_i(t), y_i) \quad s.t. w_i=(1+t)px_i + qy_i$$

where $y_i$ is distance traveled by public transport.

Answer (score 0):

One can model this scenario as a simultaneous-move strategic game, for a given $t\geq 0$:

- Set of Players: $N=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$
- Action Set $A_i$ of each player $i\in N$ is simply $\mathbb{R}_+$
- Preferences are Quasi-linear. For each $i\in N$, preferences are represented by some
  $u_i:A_1\times A_2\times\cdots\times A_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is given by
  $u_i(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=v_i(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)-tx_i$

Now one can solve for the Nash equilibrium of the above game, which may depend on the tax-rate parameter $t$.

Valuation functions $v_i$, you may consider are

- $v_i(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=a_i\sqrt{x_i}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j$, where $\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j$ is total congestion or pollution and affects the valuation of $i$ negatively, $a_i>0$ is $i$'s parameter
- $v_i(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=a_i\ln(x_i)-\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j$
- $v_i(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=f_i(x_i)-\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j$, where $f_i$ is increasing and concave.